# I keep getting an Error while using MediaPipe - still pretty new to using MediaPipe not sure how to fix this

Tags: python, mediapipe

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/anirudhakumar/PycharmProjects/SignLanguageDetector /test_classifier.py", line 22, in <module>
    mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(frame,
  File "/Users/anirudhakumar/PycharmProjects/SignLanguageDetector /venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mediapipe/python/solutions/drawing_utils.py", line 177, in draw_landmarks
    drawing_spec = connection_drawing_spec[connection] if isinstance(
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: (3, 4)
```

Code:

```
while True:
    ret, frame = capture.read()

    frame_RGB = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)  # for mediapipe need RGB image

    results = hands.process(frame_RGB)  # detects all the landmarks

    if results.multi_hand_landmarks:
        for hand_landmarks in results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(frame,
                                      hand_landmarks,
                                      mp_hands.HAND_CONNECTIONS,
                                      mp_drawing_styles.get_default_hand_landmarks_style(),
                                      mp_drawing_styles.get_default_hand_landmarks_style())

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    cv2.waitKey(25)

capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I genuinely do not know why the program is erroring. I want it to show landmark over my hands. I have also noticed that when I raise my hand the program simply shuts off. I am not entirely sure on how to continue, as I am still very new to MediaPipe - literally my first time using it.

Comment: That line doesn't appear in your code. Please show the full traceback.

Comment: I don't know MediaPipe, but I suspect you can't use `HAND_CONNECTIONS` there.